# Customization of scanning page in zbar application

Tags: iphone, customization, zbar-sdk

I am working on an application that scans the QR codes.When the scan button is clicked,it goes to the generic full page camera view.But i need to customize that page so that a logo must be shown at the bottom and a button at the top.the scanning area should be in between these two.How can i implement the?anyone have answer?the code i am using is given below

```
- (IBAction) scanButtonTapped
```

{

```
// ADD: present a barcode reader that scans from the camera feed
ZBarReaderViewController *reader = [ZBarReaderViewController new];
reader.readerDelegate = self;
reader.supportedOrientationsMask = ZBarOrientationMaskAll;

ZBarImageScanner *scanner = reader.scanner;
[scanner setSymbology: ZBAR_I25
               config: ZBAR_CFG_ENABLE
                   to: 0];
// present and release the controller
[self presentModalViewController: reader
                        animated: YES];
[reader release];
```

}

Answer (score 3):

You can set property cameraOverlayView of ZBarReaderViewController. Some docs is [here](http://zbar.sourceforge.net/iphone/sdkdoc/custom.html).

```
 ZBarReaderViewController* reader = [[ZBarReaderViewController alloc] init];
 reader.cameraOverlayView = yourCustomView;
```

To change tabBar you can add your subview.
You can access it using this:

```
 UIView* subView1 = [reader.view.subviews objectAtIndex:2];
 UIView* tabBar = [subView1.subviews objectAtIndex:0];
```

Now you can customize tabBar in the way you like.